# Get the Value of form element - without clicking on submit button

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form say i have selected Volva from drop down box . So without clicking on submit button  when i move to next field that is `<input>` the value that is volva should get store in php variable

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
<select name="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="abc" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put event on select, onBlur = saveValue();

```
 <select name="cars" onBlur = "saveValue(this.value);">
```

saveValue should be a js function, which then sends an ajax request to the server.